# Should Xcode view outlet be set or not set? Catch 22

Tags: xcode, cordova

Im building a JS app in Cordova on Xcode and getting this error message:

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x100300ec0> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

Thus I remove the view connection from the IB in accordance with multiple SO questions.

Then I end up getting this error below, for which the accepted SO answer is to build the connection between the File Owner again ;) Catch 22.

```
 loaded the "MainViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The viewcontroller MainViewController will need to have a view.

Comment: From the error message, appears that you're sending a message (you're trying to set `view`) to a wrong object (`UIApplication` instead of `UIViewController`)

Comment: Don't know about Cordova, but if it was a .xib, connection is required, and if it was a .storyboard, connection is automatic (and as such, not required).